# How to get key for a value in a list

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, key-value

Suppose I had a dictionary like this:

```
d = {'Q1': ['10', '11', '12'], 'Q2': ['01', '02', '03'], 
'Q3': ['04', '05', '06'], 'Q4': ['07', '08', '09'] }
```

And a variable: `s = '04'`
My goal is to find the key in `d` that corresponds to `s` in the list of values. So, I want to return 'Q3'.

```
 for k, v in d.items():
   for item in v:
     if s == item:
        print(d[v])
```

The above throws a `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list`. Without changing the structure of the dictionary, how can I accomplish my goal?

Comment: You want to get the key? but you all ready got it it's `K` if you do `print k` it will print `Q3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `in` to check if an element is in a list, without an additional `for` on the list:

```
d = {'Q1': ['10', '11', '12'], 'Q2': ['01', '02', '03'], 
     'Q3': ['04', '05', '06'], 'Q4': ['07', '08', '09']}

s = '04'

for k, v in d.items():
  if s in v:
    print(k, d[k])
```

output:

```
Q3 ['04', '05', '06']
```

You are getting the `TypeError` because you are trying to use a list (`v`) as a dictionary key (`d[v]`), but since lists are unhashable, they can't be keys, instead use `d[k]` which is both correct and intuitive (since `k` is `key`).